# Polymer 2.0 : How to dynamically append child in shadow dom, as append child doesn't work

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x

Getting this error message when try to add a child element :

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Comment: Can you provide some code

Comment: If you want to get an answer please post some example what you try to do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try that :

```
      // Get element from shadow dom
      var containerEle = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('shadow_dom_selector');

      // Create dynamic element
      var newEle = document.createElement('span');
      newEle.textContent = 'Hello World';

      // Append
      containerEle.appendChild(newEle);
```

If your container element have an id

```
      Polymer.dom(this.$.containerElementId).appendChild(newEle);
```

Comment: Please beware `Polymer.dom` method is legacy method. It isn't fundamental feature of Polymer 2.
https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/blob/v2.0.2/lib/legacy/polymer.dom.html#L301

Answer (score 2):

In the context of your component, for example in the ready method, try the following.

```
ready(){
    super.ready();
    this.root.appendChild(newEle);
}
```

Or from outside of the component, for example in whatever hosts your component, try the following.

```
document.querySelector("your-component-is").root.appendChild(newEle);
```